# PHP static class member scope

Tags: php, oop, scope, static-members

Let me preface this with, I come from a Java background.

What is the scope of a static class member in PHP? *ie: Request, Session, Server Lifecycle, etc*

My current understanding is that everything is **Request** unless it is stuck on the session. I have found nothing in the [Language Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to refute or confirm this.

### Example

```
class MyKlass {
    public static $K_PAGE_SIZE = 50;
    public static $K_WITH_SPRINKLES = true;
}

if (isset($_GET['NO_SPRINKLES'])) {
    MyKlass::$K_WITH_SPRINKLES = false;
}

var_dump(MyKlass::$K_WITH_SPRINKLES);
```

**Case 1**

If I were to visit a page with this code with nothing in the query line I should see

```
bool(true)
```

**Case 2**

If I were to visit the page with this code and `?NO_SPRINKLES=true` in the query line, I should see

```
bool(false)
```

**Case 3**

If I visit the page with `?NO_SPRINKLES=true` in the query line and then visit the page without it, **I should always see** `bool(true)` **right?**

**Case 4**

After visiting the page with `?NO_SPRINKLES=true`, **others who visit the page should still see** `bool(true)` **correct?**

Comment: yes.. thats the way it should work... ofcourse if you did `?NO_SPRINKLES=` you would also get false because youre testing for the presence of the key, not the value.

Comment: the time creating this well written question could have been invested in actually testing it ;)

Comment: @Dvir Azulay, absolutely true, but my purpose of posting was twofold. One, document to share with others. Two, see if anyone points to something in the documentation or offers a more detailed explanation than "this experiment passed my tests, so I'll assume it is true"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP wont retain any information unless you make use of sessions. So a variable is created at the begining of the code when you're loading the page, and destroyed at the end of the code, when it's sent.

Same with classes and their members. You can edit them as much as you want, it'll retain information, but at the very end of your script, it'll be lost.

Comment: Thanks all! **More good info from comments on raina77ow's answer** *"There is no Application Memory in PHP. Everything is created and destroyed with each Request. Even objects put into the Session are serialized and unserialized, so a static member you set in Request A will never be the same as the one in Request B"* -@Gordon. **AND** *"Yes, apache does keep a pool of PHP process to speed things up, but in theory they are all individual and "spawned and destroyed" as requests are received"* - @Alex Belanger.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about PHP, it's about HTTP Request-Response cycle. See, HTTP is specifically defined as a stateless protocol. That means each new request is processed as there was nothing before it (and will be nothing after, but that sounds too pessimistic).

Yes, there are several mechanisms of reducing this 'statelessness' - cookies, which are stored on the client-side; sessions, that use cookies or some param as keys to the information stored at the server-side. But in general your understanding is pretty correct: timespan of each entity used just by PHP (not stored in DB/file, or session) is just a **Request**.

Comment: Well it isn't **just** about the Request-Response cycle, it also depends on the server/container in which an app is deployed. In java, for instance, once the `?NO_SPRINKLES=true` page was visited, the result would be `bool(false)` for everyone who visits that page until the server instance is restarted.

Comment: Look, HTTP is _stateless_ by design: if you don't believe me, may be [this doc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) be more convincing. ) Then again, that doesn't mean you cannot implement stateful systems on its base, but then you have to store these states somewhere.

Comment: Of course HTTP is stateless, that's not what I'm saying. There are some languages/environments where objects in memory are not. So for instance if I had a simliar setup on a WebLogic environment, I could have a static class called MyKlass. That object would stay in memory regardless of whether Requests are coming or not. If one Request causes that object to be changed, then the changed object stays in memory and is accessed by the next request. This next request will also see the change.

Comment: I see, but doesn't that mean it all depends on how Requests are processed in the code itself? By the way, technically PHP can use [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.shmop.php). But persistence layer, if it's required, is much more often related to DBMS - including in-memory one (like Redis).

Comment: HTTP is simply a transport layer protocol. Its goal is to transmit data from point A to B, entirely, with a given path/request/params. The server back-end does the variable handling and everything. In fact, you could serve pages with HTTP on a server coded in Java, Python or anything, they all could use PHP as a back-end or not, as well as hold the information, or not. The point, as OP asked, is how PHP does it.

Comment: *The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is an application-level protocol...* We're reading different RFCs, right?

Comment: TRANSFER, PROTOCOL. That's in the 3 first words of my comments, you can read it again, I'm leaving it there just for you.

Comment: @comment #4 (other comments came in while I was typign), Well, what I am referring to isn't really similar to either. The link about shared memory has to do with reading and writing *nix memory segments, not allocations on the Heap. Some applications and containers share Heap memory, which was more where my question was going. It would appear to me that each PHP request has a fresh fork of the interpreter with its own Heap, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @hidden_premise: Yes, apache does keep a pool of PHP process to speed things up, but in theory they are all individual and "spawned and destroyed" as requests are received ;)

Comment: @AlexBelanger Please, learn the difference between [Transport Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) and [Application Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer).

Comment: @hidden_premise It actually depends on how PHP interpreter is called. Without giving into too much details, there's Fast-CGI way and mod-php way.

Comment: @raina77ow: I have a project to work on, I'm here simply to help people. I just said the back-end is free to handle its memory the way it wants, HTTP is simply forwarding the information from one side to another. So does FTP, and so does SMTP.. they are all TP because they are Transport Layers. Now the application layer is what the back-end is, and this is coded using a language, and now we speak of the specifications of that language. I know my difference between TP and AL, I've wasted enough time and I think OP's question is answered already.

Comment: @hidden_premise your assumption is correct. There is no Application Memory in PHP. Everything is created and destroyed with each Request. Even objects put into the Session are serialized and unserialized, so a static member you set in Request A will never be the same as the one in Request B.

Comment: @AlexBelanger You may define layers in whatever way good for you. But I had to confess: I'm lazy, and I prefer someone else to define these things for me. Like ISO, with their [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), where TCP and UDP are somehow considered Transport Layer protocols.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for your answer. We got some good stuff going here in the comments. I appreciate your sticking in there, but I don't think we were understanding each other.

Comment: * I just want to point out I found this post today and I indeed made a typo that lead raina77ow to argue with me. I meant Transport Protocol instead of Transport Layer. I didn't notice it at that time.